# Mongodb mapReduce: query another database

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mapreduce

I'm trying to write a mapReduce function for MongoDb, and have a problem trying to query data from a second MongoDb database within the reduce function.  Heres an example of the code:

```
var reduceUsers = function(key, values) {
    var reducedUser = {
        uid: key,
        count: 0,
        extractBytes: 0
    };
    var secondDb = db.getSiblingDB("second");

    ....
}
```

When I try running the mapReduce I get the following error:

```
015-09-04T15:50:23.690+0100 E QUERY    Error: map reduce failed:{
"errmsg" : "exception: ReferenceError: db is not defined\n
```

All the code is in a .js file and I run it thus:

```
> mongo mapReduceTest.js
```

Comment: Very clearly stated in the [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/mapReduce/) though you are possibly not looking at the correct page. O just gave you the correct one.  It is not possible to access top level properties such as `db`. Changed in 2.4 as is stated.

Comment: Thanks Blake.  I was hoping for an example that showed me how it can be done?

Comment: @robjwilkins Maybe you should provide sample data, what you want to achieve and the document you need as an output (if applicable). That way, maybe we could help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MapReduce can not access global shell objects like `db`. A MapReduce job can only obtain data from the one collection it runs on. It can not be used to aggregate data from more than one collection (good try, but MongoDB simply does not do JOINs). Whatever you are trying to do: it won't work this way.

When you would like advise how to solve the actual problem which lead you to this solution attempt, please open a new question which explains in detail what you are trying to do.

Comment: thanks, its my first attempt at using map reduce and I didn't realise it was limited this way.  I'll need to restructure what I'm doing if this is the case.